# How to rotate a chiral carbon

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

[image]

I know that to correctly assign R,S priorities I have to rotate the above figure until the H is projecting into the page (away from me). However, I don't know how to rotate the H and the rest of the molecule when the H is in the plane of the page.

When I imagine tilting the molecule back I get a see-saw shaped molecule ... obviously incorrect.

[image]

Comment: Envision that you are rotating the molecule on the C-Ethyl bond with the hydrogen going into the page. Remember, it won't lie flat.

Comment: Ah, I think I need to buy a model, or convert this to a Fisher projection.

Comment: You can download ACD ChemSketch, and draw the molecules. Then you can rotate them in 3D.

Comment: The "1" and "3" should be solid lines in the plane of the paper; the "4" going back as a dashed wedge as you've shown it, and the "2" being a solid wedge projecting towards the observer.

Comment: No matter whether someone is a beginner or advanced, models are extremely helpful.

Comment: One advantage of ACD ChemSketch is that you can generate the name for small molecules such as the one above: (2S)-butan-2-ol.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I'll have to check out the mentioned software. I'll also try rotating this with a model.

Comment: A recommendation three years after the fact. If you are redrawing the structure to orient the lowest priority group in the rear, don't do it. There's a good chance you might mess it up. Leave it where it is. Use your HANDS! Point the thumb of your left hand from the chiral carbon to 4 (lowest priority). Now your fingers will point in the direction 1-->2-->3. Your left hand is sinistral. S-configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Imagine viewing it from right side:

- H is upwards and CH3CH2 is downwards.
- OH is leftwards and CH3 rightwards.
- H and CH3CH2 are backwards(from right) so they must be on vertical line of Fischer projection and similarly for OH and CH3.

Alternatively:

- Put the dotted wedge CH3 in any vertical position let it be bottom.
- Then imagine all other groups to be planar, we see in clockwise order:

  - CH3CH2 , H , OH
- Draw them similarly on the Fischer projection in clockwise sense.!
  [image]

**Note that both are (S)**

Answer (score 1):

Swap number 4 for the number of the bond/molecule/atom that is pointing away from you. Decipher whether it is R/S by drawing from 1 to 3. The answer is opposite to this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x28IcxUhu3A (From 9 minutes 25 seconds on)